# jQuery JS: Using two form submits and decide what to do

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms

```
function removeComment(bID) {
    $('#submitChangeComment').attr('disabled', true);
    $.ajax({ 
        type: "POST",
        url: "misc/changeComment.php",
        data: {
            mode: 'del',
            bID : bID,
            comment : $('input[name=Comment]:visible').val() 
        }, 
        success: function(msg){
            $('#submitChangef').attr('disabled', false);
            $('#currentComment' + bID).hide();

            var $msg = $("#nowCurrentComment" + bID).find('.comment');
            // if it already has a comment, fade it out, add the text, then fade it back in
            if ($msg.text().length) {
                $msg.fadeOut('fast', function() {
                    $msg.text(msg).fadeIn('fast');
                });
            } else {
                // otherwise just hide it, add the text, and then fade it in
                $msg.hide().text(msg).fadeIn('fast'); 
            }
        }
    });
}
```

```
function FriendChangeComment(bID) {
    $('#submitChangef').attr('disabled', true);
    $.ajax({ 
        type: "POST",
        url: "misc/changeComment.php",
        data: {
            mode: 'edit',
            bID : bID,
            comment : $('input[name=Comment]:visible').val() 
        }, 
        success: function(msg) {
            $('#submitChangef').attr('disabled', false);
            $('#currentComment' + bID).hide();

            var $msg = $("#nowCurrentComment" + bID).find('.comment');
            // if it already has a comment, fade it out, add the text, then fade it back in
            if ( $msg.text().length ) {
                $msg.fadeOut('fast', function() {
                    $msg.text( msg ).fadeIn('fast');
                });
            } else {
                // otherwise just hide it, add the text, and then fade it in
                $msg.hide().text( msg ).fadeIn('fast'); 
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Form:

```
<form action="javascript:FriendChangeComment(<? echo $showInfo["bID"]; ?>)" method="post">
change comment for <br><?php echo fullname($showInfo["bID"]); ?>:<br>
<input type="text" name="Comment" value="<?=$showC["comment"];?>" size="20">  
<input name="submit" type="submit" id="submitChangef" value="Save">
<input name="removeC" type="button" id="submitremoveComment" value="remove" onClick="">
</form>
```

I have two submit buttons in one form. If you click on the first "submitChangef" I want it to run FriendChangeComment(), if you click on the "removeComment" i want it to run removeComment. Both are the same functions, only difference between them is the mode: (del, edit) in the ajax data. I dont know how I can shorten the code and make it simple, as they both are complete duplicates of eachother(almost).

How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the `bID` as an hidden input field to your form and move your event binding to jQuery instead of doing it in the form itself, then pass the `bID` and mode as a parameter to the function:

```
$('#submitChangef').click(function() {
    bID = $(this).closest('form').find('#bID').val();
    changeComment(bID, 'edit');
    return false;
});

$('#submitremoveComment').click(function() {
    bID = $(this).closest('form').find('#bID').val();
    changeComment(bID, 'del');
    return false;
});

function changeComment(bID, mode) {
    $('#submitChangeComment').attr('disabled', true);
    $.ajax({ 
        type: "POST",
        url: "misc/changeComment.php",
        data: {
            mode: mode,
            bID : bID,
            comment : $('input[name=Comment]:visible').val() 
        }, 
        success: function(msg){
            $('#submitChangef').attr('disabled', false);
            $('#currentComment' + bID).hide();

            var $msg = $("#nowCurrentComment" + bID).find('.comment');
            // if it already has a comment, fade it out, add the text, then fade it back in
            if ($msg.text().length) {
                $msg.fadeOut('fast', function() {
                    $msg.text(msg).fadeIn('fast');
                });
            } else {
                // otherwise just hide it, add the text, and then fade it in
                $msg.hide().text(msg).fadeIn('fast'); 
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i'd use one function for your needs and one hidden form param, eg:
form:

```
<form id='myform' method="post">
change comment for <br><?php echo fullname($showInfo["bID"]); ?>:<br>
<input type="text" name="Comment" value="<?=$showC["comment"];?>" size="20">  
<input name="submit" type="submit" onclick="processBtnClick(this, 'edit');" value="Save">
<input name="removeC" type="button" onclick="processBtnClick(this, 'remove');" value="remove" onClick="">
<input type='hidden' name='action' id='action'/>
</form>
```

js:

```
function processBtnClick(bID, action){
  $('#action').value(action);
  $('#myform').submit();
```

/*or your .ajax code
  $.ajax({ 
       type: "POST",
       url: "misc/changeComment.php",
       ...
*/
    }

php (or something else):

```
 if ($_POST['action']=='remove')
      do_remove_stuff();
    else
      do_edit_stuff();
```